# How to pass an existing environment variable in a Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Assuming the host machine has the `TESTVARIABLE` set

```bash
user@hostmachine> echo $TESTVARIABLE
test_value
```

How can you pass this variable to a container with docker-compose, using an .envfile or the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Most answers I find, involve explicitly defining that value in an .envfile, or directly in the `docker-compose.yml`, or in the command line when executing the `up` command`. However, I am looking to pass an **existing** variable on the host machine to the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that `TESTVARIABLE` is actually exported to your environment and isn't just a shell variable:

```
export TESTVARIABLE
```

Then you can simply refer to it in your `docker-compose.yaml` like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  example:
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    command:
      - sleep
      - inf
    environment:
      - "TESTVARIABLE=${TESTVARIABLE}"
```

If I run:

```
$ export TESTVARIABLE=foo
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker-compose exec example env
```

I will get output like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=68705fc07b09
TERM=xterm
TESTVARIABLE=foo
HOME=/root
```

There you can see the value of `TESTVARIABLE` from the local environment.

---

Note that if `TESTVARIABLE` is not defined in your environment, `docker-compose` will warn you:

```
$ docker-compose up
WARNING: The TESTVARIABLE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
...
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed the variable was not exported to the environment.